# If antimatter can be interpreted as matter moving back in time, could we in theory send information to the past?

Tags: antimatter, time-travel

I am pretty sure the answer is going to bo "no", but I would still like to have a physicist explanation.

If I can create a device that can change the probability of a positron annihilation, would it affect the probability of positron creation in the past, in a way that could be observed?

Comment: Moving back in time violates the fundamentals of thermodynamics. It is not possible to travel back in time, even when many equations are time invariant

Answer (score 2):

[image: e-e+]  [image: tracks]

> The lines in this picture are trails of bubbles formed as charged particles force their way through an unstable mixture of neon and hydrogen. They curve in an applied magnetic field, and spiral because they lose energy quickly.

> T[he highlighted tracks](https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm) are antielectrons, each of which is part of an electron-positron () pair that has 'materialized’ from a high energy photon in the field of a nucleus. This is often referred to as 'pair-production’

On the left of the picture is an electron positron pair created by a gamma . Both the electron and positron are particles with the same kinematics, positrons are not moving backwards in time, as you can see in the record of the tracks they leave in the bubble chamber.

You ask:

> If antimatter can be interpreted as matter moving back in time

This is a mathematical interpretation of the integrals used to calculate the interactions of particles( antiparticles included in the name), the [Feynman diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Feynman_diagrams). It makes life easy in the calculations, in keeping track of conservation laws (charge, lepton number , baryon number ....) in the calculations.

[Here is a term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Feynman_diagrams#/media/File:Electron-positron-annihilation.svg) in the diagrams needed for the annihilation of an electron with a positron.

[image: e+e-]

The convention in the drawing is that time increases to the right. Defining the positron as an electron going backwards keeps track of the quantum numbers for the interaction and simplifies its representation.

So the answer is no, one cannot use feynman diagram mathematical representations to send messages to the real past.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess my first question should have been: are antiparticle actually moving backward in time?  I assumed this was a possible interpretation and not just a math trick.  In the bubble chamber, I can somehow imagine the pair creation as a positron arriving from the future and then changing its time direction giving the impression of a pair creation.  I am not a physicist, so I'll accept your answer that this is not in fact what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

"Send to the past" is often interpreted to mean that somehow the physical processes across the entire universe are put dramatically into reverse gear (so to speak), except for some small local thing like a person or a particle.

I would argue that such ideas are completely unscientific fantasies.

Whilst it is possible for representations of the past to exist - such as through human memory, through videos and photographs, or through written records - there is absolutely no evidence that the past continues to exist as a physical place to which things can actually be "sent".

Whilst it is possible for physicists to share in popular fantasies, there is nothing in *physics* to suggest the existence of this past.

There is no experiment that shows the past to exist, and there is no theory which requires the past to exist as part of its explanation for how the physical world works.

The origin of the idea about the existence of the past, is not from physics at all, but from science fiction. You could as well be asking whether warp drives are possible in theory, wormholes possible in theory, or the transfer of fly DNA into a living human possible in theory.

There is no scientific observation of such mechanisms, nor any current theory originating from scientific work which explains the world in terms of these mechanisms.

So to that extent, no, you cannot send information into the past according to any existing theory in physics, because there is no theory in physics which even asserts the existence of the past.

Comment: "there is no theory in physics which even asserts the existence of the past." -- I think I know what you are trying to say, but to me this statement is worded too strongly. For example, we observe the cosmic microwave background radiation, and cosmology asserts that this radiation was generated during recombination, a process that occurred in the past. Perhaps a better wording might be "asserts the existence of the past **as a place one can send information**"?

Comment: @Andrew, I'm going further and saying I'm not aware of any scientific theory that relies at all on the past as a place in existence. You cannot send information there, and you cannot receive information from there either (except in the usual way that some representation has already been maintained into the present, and thus exists in the present, like a photograph or a fossil). The past is our conceptualisation of a present that used to exist and which we can remember - that conceptualisation has no physical reality, and our recollections are not a place that exists in the physical world.

Comment: I see. In that case I have to quite strongly disagree. I think the past "existing" in a straightforward sense is the best scientific explanation of observations like the fossil record and the cosmic microwave background radiation. As I understand it, your point of view would be consistent with a creationist theory where the Universe is six thousand years old and "God made the light in transit" to appear as if the Universe was consistent with standard cosmology. I don't think this is consistent with the understanding of modern science.

Comment: @Andrew, no I think you've gravely misunderstood. My argument is not that the very distant past didn't exist - it's that it doesn't exist now. The fossils originate in the past, but they exist only in the present, and the past where they originated no longer exists. I agree creationist codswallop is not consistent with science, but that is for a very straightforward reason: its supernatural explanations violate the naturalist and determinist tenets of science.

Comment: In that case I'd still stand by my earlier comment at, as written, "there is no theory in physics which even asserts the existence of the past," is too strong a statement. I think I understand what you're saying, but I just think the way that is worded opens the door to being misunderstood, for example as in the creationist example. Anyway, it's your answer :) So feel free to ignore. This is just meant as a friendly suggestion.

Comment: @Andrew, well which theory does assert the existence of the past? If we both accept that we cannot communicate back and forth with the past, then experimental justification is ruled out. What remains can only be a theory whose internal explanatory logic depends on assuming the existence of the past (and probably in a corresponding way, the existence of the future, even before its occurrence), but I'm not aware of any theory in physics which requires this approach. (1/2)

Comment: Obviously also, what I mean by a "theory in physics" is more than a free-standing conjecture on a single issue, but a system of conjectures, connected together by reasoning, and which explains most or all phenomena. So as I say, I'm not aware that any theory requires the past (or future) to exist concurrently with the present. Also, for clarity, I think what I'm arguing here goes under the name of "presentism". (2/2)